# SSL certificate works on desktop but seen as untrusted when accessing API on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ssl, nginx

So I have nginx (SSL, proxy) sitting in front of my node app. When I access the app via browser, it works fine. It looks like [this](http://cl.ly/image/1M2d0N1i1z2Z).

However, when I try to access it via my Ionic app (iOS app), I got untrusted error instead.

Any idea why it happens? I double check that `Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2` is included in iOS 8.

Comment: Check with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look for chain issues, like "extra download". Desktop browsers will often fill in missing chain certificates not sent by the server while other applications will not.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich the thing is I can't do this. It's a dev server accessible via vpn only.

Answer (score 0):

Some SSL providers like Go Daddy come with a bunch of intermediate certificates as a separate file like **gd_bundle.crt**. You might need to make sure your SSL setup is including them

If your using apache its an easy config line

```
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/certs/gd_bundle.crt
```

Havent worked with nginx, but sounds you need to combine it manually to your end certificate,

```
$ cat www.example.com.crt gd_bundle.crt > www.example.com.chained.crt
```

see section 'SSL certificate chains' http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html